# Passing a dynamic variable into an array index

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Adding a new function to update an existing PHP function. 
I am currently trying to get this output:

```
Array ( [1477] => Array ( [qty] => 3 ))
```

The 1477 is the index. Currently, when I run my code it obviously returns the following:

```
Array
(
    [cartnum] => 1478
    [qty] => 1
)
```

Below is the code I am running. If anyone could point me into the right direction, I would appreciate it.

```
  function updateMapproval(url){
    var quan = jQuery("#item_<?php echo $item->getId() ?>").val();
    var set = "update_qty"
    var _cartnum = '<?php echo $item->getId() ?>';

    var cart = {
        cartnum: _cartnum,
        qty: quan
    };

    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data: {
            update_cart_action:set,
            cart: cart},
        url: url,
        success: function(data){
            console.log(data);
        }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you just want to assign `qty: 3` to the nth element of your cart array, in that case change

```
var cart = {
  cartnum: _cartnum,
  qty: quan
};
```

To this

```js
let cart = [];
let _cartnum = 2; // 1477
let q = 3;

// ...

cart[_cartnum] = {qty: q};

console.log(cart);
```

Comment: This is close, and I have been messing with it. For some reason it sends over a large number of empty arrays.  Array ( [0] => [1] => [2] =>... etc